# Deduce the accurate month by the number of the days

Tags: c++

I've got a function that extracts the month from a given number of days( days > 0 && days < 366):

```
int findMonth(int days)
{
    int i, months[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    for (i = 0; i < 12 && days > 0;i++)
        days -= months[i];
    return i;    
}
```

Is there any more rational way to deduce it?(I am ignoring the leap year)

Comment: You simply ignored leap years?

Comment: Yes, i am ignoring it.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly cromulent way to go about figuring out the month from the days.  Maybe at the beginning an `assert(days > 0);` and `assert(days < 366);`, with a `#include <cassert>` as the last include at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make it shorter I think you can't. If you just want something different and maybe more close to C++, you can try this:

```
int findMonth(int days) {
    int i = 0, months[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    return std::count_if(std::begin(months), std::end(months), [&i, &days](int x) { return (i += x) - x <= days; });
}
```

or using `std::vector`:

```
int findMonth(int days) {
    int i = 0;
    std::vector<int> months = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    return std::count_if(months.begin(), months.end(), [&i, &days](int x) { return (i += x) - x <= days; });   
}
```